# Spring Boot jar no main manifest error

Tags: spring, ubuntu, spring-boot, jar

I want to upload my Spring Boot app to production, but when I build JAR file and upload to my Ubuntu server I am getting this error:

> no main manifest in jar file

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.blockisland</groupId>
<artifactId>BlockIsland</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>BlockIsland</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <!-- Adds Tomcat and Spring MVC, along others, jackson-databind included transitively -->
    <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>      

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/materializecss -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>materializecss</artifactId>
        <version>0.100.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/font-awesome -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.blockisland.BootApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How do you build your jar? How do you run it on your production box?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need:

```
<plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.blockisland.BootApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` takes care of building the application with all dependencies bundled in it.